# tryCatch syntax in R

Tags: r, try-catch

Can't understand why hasRaised$status is still zero after I catched the error.

```
setAnswer <-function(n){stop("Wrong Answer")}

hasRaised = list(status=0, e_message = "") 
tryCatch(setAnswer(42),
    error = function(e) {print(e$message); hasRaised$status = 1; hasRaised$e_message = e$message;}) 
if(hasRaised$status==0){stop("FailedToRise_getAnswer")}
```

How to modify a "global" variable from the error function?

Comment: Use `<<-` instead of `=`: `function(e) {print(e$message); hasRaised$status <<- 1; hasRaised$e_message <<- e$message;}`

Comment: or keep it as is and add a line `hasRaised <<- hasRaised` below what you have. you should also add some line breaks and remove semicolons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the error messagaes and use the finally argument in the `tryCatch` function. See below:

```
setAnswer <-function(n){stop("Wrong Answer")}

hasRaised = list(status=0, e_message = "") 

tryCatch(setAnswer(42),
     error = function(e) print(e$message), 
     finally = {hasRaised$status = 1; hasRaised$e_message = e$message;}) 

if(hasRaised$status==0){stop("FailedToRise_getAnswer")}
```